# Disable specific keyboard event of qslider

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qslider

I am using qslider in python 3. I can move cursor forward and backward by keyboard event of up, down, left and right arrow.  I would like to disable specifically part of them: up and down arrow move cursor while right and left cursor do not. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the keyPressEvent method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Slider(QtWidgets.QSlider):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, QtCore.Qt.Key_Right):
            return
        super(Slider, self).keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    slider = Slider()
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    slider.valueChanged.connect(label.setNum)
    label.setNum(slider.value())
    lay.addWidget(slider)
    lay.addWidget(label)
    w.resize(160, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```